# A way to have an unchecked "end date" input field?

Tags: javascript, datetime

The [date module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) gives the possiblity to collect an end date.
The thing is, in the node creation form, 'Show end date' is checked by default and the date calendar popup field is displayed.
[image: As shown in this screenshot]

I would like to have the opposite scenario.
With the **End date** field hidden by default, and it would only appear if we check the 'Show end date' checkbox.
[image: As shown in this screenshot]

Thanks to anyone who can help with this

Answer (score 1):

We can do this easily using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) hook, by setting `#checked` value of checkbox to `FALSE`. Since the date module doesn't add both fields at initial form load, we've to add [#after_build](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#after_build) to form where we can modify `#checked` value of checkbox (i.e. `show_todate` field) in form.

Below is the sample code for hiding the end date in date field. For this we've to add a Date Type field (field name as `field_date`) with ability to add end date in article Content Type. After which we've to implement hook_form_alter and checked if current form is add new article form to make sure we don't override node edit field value. And then added `#after_build` to add article form. Which then set the `#checked` value to `FALSE`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function [MODULE_NAME]_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'article_node_form':
      if (empty($form['nid']['#value'])) {
        $form['#after_build'][] = '_modify_end_date_form';
      }
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Proxy function to call _modify_end_date_form_after_build().
 * @param type $form
 * @param type $form_state
 * @return void
 */
function _modify_end_date_form($form, &$form_state) {
  return _modify_end_date_form_after_build($form, $form_state);
}

/**
 * After_build callback for Article Content Type.
 * @param type $form
 * @param type $form_state
 * @return void
 */
function _modify_end_date_form_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['field_date'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['show_todate']['#checked'] = FALSE;
  // $form['field_date'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['show_todate']['#value'] = FALSE;
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: When implementing the first form_alter hook what module name would you target ? I tried `_modify_end_date_form_alter` and since i want this in the event content type, i replaced `article_node_form` with `event_node_form` but nothing happens. I'm doing something wrong but i don't know what. I really appreciate you taking time to help @Yogesh !

Comment: Module name is the module file name, i.e. if your module file name is `drupal_custom.module` then you've to use `drupal_custom_form_alter` as function name. After implementing this clear site cache. Other things are correct.

Comment: Well it's not working.
Maybe i should've mentioned that i only know very basic php and I've never opened a module file or delved into drupal core. So it's like i'm discovering a totally new dimension here. Everything looks exciting, scary and mysterious at the same time.
Where should i paste those 3 functions ? I tried putting them into `date.module` and named the first module name `date_form_alter` but it doesn't seem like a good idea.   I tried `_modify_end_date_form_alter` but it's not good either. Sorry for being this bad. I'm learning :)

Comment: @amstram, No worries, check out this documentation on [Creating custom modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules). This will give you some insights on basics of module in Drupal. `hook_form_alter` is hook, check how to implement guide [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/writing-comments-and-implementing-your-first-hook). Keep `_modify_end_date_form` and `_modify_end_date_form_after_build` function as it is, as these are custom functions written by us.